# For which whole number n is the expression reducible to simpler terms?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't seem to figure this one out. I have the expression: $$\frac{7n+2}{3n-1}$$

I realize that in order for it to be reducible, $7n+2$ has to be divisible by $3n-1$, so $7n+2 = (3n-1)k$. From here it follows that $n = \frac{-2-k}{7-3k}$ where $k$ is a whole number. From here on I'm lost, I can't think of any properties of this equation. How should I think about this?

Comment: Hint:  $3n-1$ divides $6n-2$.

Comment: I don't understand how this hint helps me... I've been thinking but can't draw any conclusions...

Comment: What I got from the hint now is that n can be -4. But the problem says that I need to find the general solution (every n)

Comment: $|3n-1|$ is much bigger than $|n+4|$, for most $n$. There's only a small handful of values of $n$ you need to check, so it's a finite problem.

Comment: Note:  you specified "whole number" which I took to mean an integer $>0$, or possibly $≥0$.  If you really meant "integer" you should say that.  Doesn't change the method, but of course the answer will be different.

Comment: I see... I still don't understand the method though... Is the way that I think about this correct? What method did you use to get to the conclusion so fast?'

Comment: The solution in the textbook is n = 13k-4, and I'm wondering how to get there

Comment: I don't understand that answer.  Taking $k=1$ we get $n=13-4=9$.  If we substitute $n=9$ in your expression we get $\frac {65}{26}$, right?

Comment: Oh, I think you misstated the problem.  You asked for values of $n$ for which $3n-1$ divided $7n+2$.  I think you meant to ask for values of $n$ for which $\gcd(7n+2,3n-1)>1$.  For $n=9$, say, we have $\gcd(65, 26)=13>1$.  My comments were all about divisibility, not the gcd.

Comment: For the corrected question, it's fairly easy to show that the gcd is either $1$ or $13$, so you just need to analyze the case where it is $13$.

Comment: Yup, I just realized I completely misinterpreted the problem. It's asking for which n does the expression have at least one common factor in the numerator and the denominator. Sorry for wasting your time haha. So gcd > 1 yes...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149309/discussion-between-mixoftwo-and-lulu).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know about partial fraction decomposition:
$$
\frac{7n + 2}{3n - 1} = \frac{6n - 2 + n + 4}{3n - 1} = \frac{2(3n - 1) + n + 4}{3n - 1} = 2 + \frac{n + 4}{3n - 1} 
$$

Here I assume by "whole number" you mean integer, and $\frac{a}{b}$ can only be an integer if either $a = 0$ or $|a| \geq |b|$ (otherwise it would be a rational number with absolute value less than $1$). With that we need to have $\frac{n + 4}{3n - 1}$ be an integer by having $n$ satisfy $\begin{cases} n + 4 = 0 \\ |n + 4| \geq |3n - 1| \end{cases}$. Now, can you solve for all $n$ that satisfy the condition, list all the "whole numbers" n in that solution, and make a table of them to see which ones result in $\frac{n + 4}{3n - 1}$ being an integer, which in turn makes $\frac{7n + 2}{3n - 1}$ an integer.

Answer (score 1):

We find the $G.C.D.$ of the two polynomials in the numerator and denominator respectively.

$$GCD(7n+2,3n-1) = GCD(n+4, 3n-1) = GCD(n+4,n-9) = GCD(13,n-9)$$

We now wish that this GCD isn’t $1$, for the fraction to be reducible. Or that $$\pmod {13}: $$$$ n \equiv 9 \equiv -4 $$ or that $n=13k-4 \ \ \ k \in Z$.